# Value of type 'SCNVector3' has no member 'length'

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit

So I've made a testgame with Scenekit and used the default game template to do it. In my code i set the ball speed to a constant velocity of 1.0 so that there is control over the physical behavior like so:

```
var ballNode: SCNNode!
... 
ballNode = gameScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Ball", recursively:
        true)!
...
ballNode.physicsBody?.velocity.length = 1.0
```

This worked out perfectly, however, when I created a new game template from xcode with a '`single page application`' template, and recreated the exact same code with additional transitions between scenes, I'm not able to access the `velocity.length`.

error given:

```
Value of type 'SCNVector3' has no member 'length'
```

how I want it to be: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fpgac.png)
how it is: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3DNh.png)

So what am I missing ? the only difference in code I can think of is the different template I used to create the game.

Comment: Is your working project using a pod or some other way to extend SCNVector3?  length isn't part of the built-in class

Comment: Command-click on `length` in your first project to see where it is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your screenshot, it looks like you might have this .swift file copied into your project

https://github.com/wesmatlock/MarbleMazer/blob/master/MarbleMaze/GameUtils/SCNVector3%2BExtensions.swift

It's the only one I could find where `length` was a settable var, not a function, and other functions seem to match.